# python dictionary to user input

Tags: python, dictionary

```
referred_rankings_men = {
'ryan': ['lizzy', 'sarah', 'zoey', 'daniella'],
'josh': ['sarah', 'lizzy', 'daniella', 'zoey'],
'blake': ['sarah', 'daniella', 'zoey', 'lizzy'],
'connor': ['lizzy', 'sarah', 'zoey', 'daniella']
}
```

I am just a beginner in python and i want to convert the above python dictionary to user input i tried with the following code :

```
n = int(input("enter the no of men"))

lis1 = []
for i in range(n):
    man = input("enter the man")
    for j in range(n):
        woman = input("enter the woman")
        lis1.append(woman)
        preferred_rankings_men[man] = lis1

print(preferred_rankings_men)
```

but I am not getting the correct result.

Comment: What is the correct result? What do you mean converting to user input?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: <crystal ball mode=on>haha reset `lis1 = []` in the inner loop, or you only have one loop<crystal ball mode=off>

Comment: the correct result should be same as the above dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want to generate `preferred_rankings_men` in the desired format by using user inputs. In that case, your code has a simple bug, just reinitalize `lis1` within the loop

```
n = int(input("enter the no of men"))
preferred_rankings_men = {}
for i in range(n):
    man = input("enter the man ")
    lis1 = []
    for j in range(n):
        woman = input("enter the woman ")
        lis1.append(woman)
        preferred_rankings_men[man] = lis1

print(preferred_rankings_men)
```